# Outer Joins with Null values on Multiple columns

Tags: ms-access

I m trying to compute sth like a running total but I cannot make this work for types that are not in the baseline. Here is my simplified datatable:

```
╔══════════╦═══════╦══════╦═════════╗
║   Date   ║ store ║ type ║ LTD_PnL ║
╠══════════╬═══════╬══════╬═════════╣
║ 20141230 ║ ABC   ║ 2015 ║      10 ║
║ 20150102 ║ ABC   ║ 2015 ║      20 ║
║ 20150102 ║ ABC   ║ 2016 ║      22 ║
║ 20150103 ║ ABC   ║ 2015 ║      23 ║
║ 20150103 ║ ABC   ║ 2016 ║      23 ║
╚══════════╩═══════╩══════╩═════════╝
```

Now I would like to compute the YTD PnL with 20141230 the base case. Here is the output I expect to get:

```
╔══════════╦═══════╦══════╦═════════╗
║   Date   ║ store ║ type ║ YTD_PnL ║
╠══════════╬═══════╬══════╬═════════╣
║ 20150102 ║ ABC   ║ 2015 ║      10 ║
║ 20150102 ║ ABC   ║ 2016 ║      22 ║
║ 20150103 ║ ABC   ║ 2015 ║      13 ║
║ 20150103 ║ ABC   ║ 2016 ║      23 ║
╚══════════╩═══════╩══════╩═════════╝
```

Here is my MS Access SQL:

```
select 
 t1.Date, t1.store, t1.type, 
 SUM(t1.LTD_PnL) - SUM(NZ(t2.LTD_PnL,0)) AS YTD_PnL
from PnLTable AS t1 LEFT JOIN PnLTable AS t2 ON t1.store=t2.store AND t1.type = t2.type
Where t1.Date >"20141230" AND t2.Date = "20141230"
GROUP BY t1.Date, t1.store, t1.type;
```

This outputs the correct data for type=2015 but does not return anything for type=2016. I thought because I do a LEFT JOIN it should return all values in t1 and only those that are there for t2 and further that the NZ takes care of the null values.

Could somebody please point me into the right direction and tell me where I m going wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [subqueries](http://allenbrowne.com/subquery-01.html).  When you specify a WHERE clause on a left-joined table, Jet/ACE (the Access db engine) essentially treats it like an INNER JOIN.

Try this instead:

```
select 
 t1.Date, t1.store, t1.type, 
 SUM(t1.LTD_PnL) - SUM(NZ(t2.LTD_PnL,0)) AS YTD_PnL
from PnLTable AS t1 LEFT JOIN 
  (SELECT store, type, LTD_PnL FROM PnLTable WHERE PnLTable.Date="20141230") AS t2 
  ON t1.store=t2.store AND t1.type = t2.type
Where t1.Date >"20141230"
GROUP BY t1.Date, t1.store, t1.type;
```

You may find it easier to save the subquery as a separate query def to make your main query more readable.